# Why does keras (SGD) optimizer.minimize() not reach global minimum in this example?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, minimize, sgd

I'm in the process of completing a TensorFlow tutorial via DataCamp and am transcribing/replicating the code examples I am working through in my own Jupyter notebook.

Here are the original instructions from the coding problem :

[image]

I'm running the following snippet of code and am not able to arrive at the same result that I am generating within the tutorial, which I have confirmed are the correct values via a connected scatterplot of x vs. loss_function(x) as seen a bit further below.

```
# imports
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import Variable, keras

def loss_function(x):
    import math
    return 4.0*math.cos(x-1)+np.divide(math.cos(2.0*math.pi*x),x)

# Initialize x_1 and x_2
x_1 = Variable(6.0, np.float32)
x_2 = Variable(0.3, np.float32)

# Define the optimization operation
opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

for j in range(100):
    # Perform minimization using the loss function and x_1
    opt.minimize(lambda: loss_function(x_1), var_list=[x_1])
    # Perform minimization using the loss function and x_2
    opt.minimize(lambda: loss_function(x_2), var_list=[x_2])

# Print x_1 and x_2 as numpy arrays
print(x_1.numpy(), x_2.numpy())
```

I draw a quick connected scatterplot to confirm (successfully) that the loss function that I using gets me back to the same graph provided by the example (seen in screenshot above)

```
# Generate loss_function(x) values for given range of x-values
losses = []
for p in np.linspace(0.1, 6.0, 60):
    losses.append(loss_function(p))

# Define x,y coordinates
x_coordinates = list(np.linspace(0.1, 6.0, 60))
y_coordinates = losses

# Plot
plt.scatter(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
plt.title('Plot of Input values (x) vs. Losses')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('loss_function(x)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here are the resulting global and local minima, respectively, as per the DataCamp environment :

[image]

***4.38*** is the correct global minimum, and ***0.42*** indeed corresponds to the first local minima on the graphs RHS (when starting from x_2 = 0.3)

And here are the results from my environment, both of which move opposite the direction that they should be moving towards when seeking to minimize the loss value:

[image]

I've spent the better part of the last 90 minutes trying to sort out why my results disagree with those of the DataCamp console / why the optimizer fails to minimize this loss for this simple toy example...?

I appreciate any suggestions that you might have after you've run the provided code in your own environments, many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the difference in outputs arose from the default precision of tf.division() (vs np.division()) and tf.cos() (vs math.cos()) -- operations which were specified in (my transcribed, "custom") definition of the loss_function().

The loss_function() had been predefined in the body of the tutorial and when I "inspected" it using the *inspect package* ( using inspect.getsourcelines(loss_function) ) in order to redefine it in my own environment, the output of said inspection didn't clearly indicate that tf.division & tf.cos had been used instead of their NumPy counterparts (which my version of the code had used).

The actual difference is quite small, but is apparently sufficient to push the optimizer in the opposite direction (away from the two respective minima).

After swapping in tf.division() and tf.cos  (as seen below) I was able to arrive at the same results as seen in the DC console.

***Here is the code for the loss_function that will back in to the same results as seen in the console (screenshot) :***

```
def loss_function(x):
    import math
    return 4.0*tf.cos(x-1)+tf.divide(tf.cos(2.0*math.pi*x),x)
```